# LateInitializationError: Field 'initialPosition' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am trying to create map screen but I found the below error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown building Consumer<MapViewModel>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<MapViewModel>]):
LateInitializationError: Field 'initialPosition' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer<MapViewModel> file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/Air%20Forces/aireforces/lib/screens/BaseScreen.dart:44:14
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MapViewModel.initialPosition (package:airforces/screens/map/viewmodel/map_viewmodel.dart)
#1      MapScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:airforces/screens/map/view/map_screen.dart:19:27)
#2      Consumer.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:180:19)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:259:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4648:28)
...
====================================================================================================
```

and this is the below `ViewModel` I have:

```
import 'package:airforces/enums/ScreenState.dart';
import 'package:airforces/screens/BaseViewModel.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  late LatLng? initialPosition;
  late LatLng lastMapPosition = initialPosition!;

  void getUserLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude, position.longitude);
    initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    print('${placemarks[0].name}');
    setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }
}
```

and this is the below map screen I have:

```
import 'package:airforces/screens/BaseScreen.dart';
import 'package:airforces/screens/map/viewmodel/map_viewmodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseScreen<MapViewModel>(
      onFinish: (_) {
      },
      onModelReady: (mapViewModel) {
        mapViewModel.getUserLocation();
      },
      builder: (context, mapViewModel, child){
        return GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: mapViewModel.initialPosition!,
          ),
          myLocationEnabled: true,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occurring because `initialPosition` is `null` until the `late` initialization occurs, but it is being converted to a non-nullable type before the late initialization occurs here: `mapViewModel.initialPosition!`.

You can resolve this one of two ways.

1. Return a default position if `initialPosition` is `null` when accessing it.

```
target: mapViewModel.initialPosition ?? [defaultPosition];
```

2. Display a loading widget until `initialPosition` is initialized, then display `GoogleMap`.

Both of these solutions will require a minor state management solution in order to update the widget when `initialPosition` is finally initialized.